# Ошибка при взаимодействии с бд pythonanywhere

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot, pythonanywhere

Выгрузил бота на pythonanywhere, при попытке запуска выдается ошибка в синтаксисе использования базы данных. При том, что на windows все работало, интегрировал на линукс и там тоже все работало - только на pythonanywhere проблемы. Нашел как использовать базы данных в pythonanywhere с примером(https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/7666/), но это тоже не помогло. База данных точно загружена и все остальные файлы тоже.

Весь код писал именно на Windows, но еще раз повторюсь, на линуксе все отлично работало

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/bin/pythonanywhere_runner.py", line 26, in _pa_run
    code = compile(f.read(), filename.encode("utf8"), "exec")
  File "/home/Nanasee/casino_bot.py", line 45
    cur.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id = {message.chat.id}")
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Вот еще кусочек кода который взаимодействует с бд

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    con = sqlite3.connect("dannie_2.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id = {message.chat.id}")
    if cur.fetchone()[0] == 0:
```

Comment: Мне кажется, Вам мешают ограничения бесплатного экаунта. Он у Вас бесплатный? вторая возможная причина - права на доступ к файлу. Правда, не знаю, как их проверить - при бесплатном экаунте ssh доступа то нету... разве что из самого питона?

Comment: ограничения питонэнивер заключаются только в количестве запущенных терминалов одновременно и квоте на мегабайты, хоть аккаунт и бесплатный, все должно работать. у меня есть ещё один проект, в котором тоже есть бд, но он работает.

Comment: Тогда - пока загадка. Непонятно, почему не работает...

Comment: Проверьте, что используется версия Python не ниже 3.6. В более ранних версиях нет f-строк, которые вы используете для передачи аргументов в запрос.

Comment: @insolor я кажется деплоил подобный проект с f-строками, но возможно и не использовал их, точно не помню. Я принял решение все же уйти с pythonanywhere на heroku, там все более стабильно. Но спасибо что поднимаете тему, возможно кому-то это поможет.